# Using Reflection, can we find the methods effected in a changelist(check-in), given line numbers in a source file, that has changes

Tags: c#, reflection

Using Reflection, can we find the methods effected in a changelist(check-in), we have line numbers that has the changes in a source file.
Using C# reflection we can get methods in module/class. I am not sure how to find methods that belong for a given line number. 
The plan is to run all the tests that call these methods, that have changes.
Any ideas friends?
Thanks!

Comment: That's not stored in the metadata reflection reads. You'd either need to parse a PDB file, or perhaps using Roslyn to parse the source files, but no reflection can't help you here.

Comment: Personally though, I would say it's a good idea to rerun all tests. As an example, let's say in the past `MethodA` set `NeverRunAgain = true`, but `MethodB` did not touch it. Now in the new change you decide `MethodB `sets `NeverRunAgain = false`. Well if I rerun all my `MethodB` tests, they'll probably be fine, however I may well have broken some of the tests for `MethodA` since `MethodB` now has a new side-effect. Looking at the code I might not notice one `MethodA` test calls `MethodB` because it happens 30 stack frames deep.